# Specifying login creditials for remote SQL connection string in ASP.Net/Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db to learn how to use the new .Net Core and Entity Framework Core and I am trying to create the connection string to a remote SQL Server. I updated the server and database strings but it does not show how to specify the username and password. I have done some digging but every entity framework core example I find is for localDB only. How am I to properly specify the login credentials and what should `Trusted_Connection` be set to for a remote SQL Server 2016 server?

Comment: You can replace user id and password for connection string in DbContext with dependency injection, have you tried that ?

Comment: @H.Herzl Huh? I am asking how to specify it in the base connection string.

Comment: Google is your friend... http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: It's the same connection string, e.g.: server=(local);database=Foo;user id=name;password=123;

Comment: @Tseng I was googleing just never found that page. Thanks for the link. If you want to use the first "standard security" and link to the page as an answer I will mark it as so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The connection strings in EF Core remain the same as in EF6 and when you use pure ADO.NET.

For user/password authentication it's `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`.

For a list of common connection strings for SQL Server (and others), look at https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/.

Answer (score 1):

There is small difference in the connection string for the core.[You can find it in the MSDN Blog.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/09/net-core-data-access/)

we need to specify the server port number in the connection string.

```
 Server = tcp:<ServerName>,<PortName>; Database = <DataBaseName>; User Id = <UserName>; Password = <Password>;
```

To get the server port number using the following query.

```
 select distinct local_net_address, local_tcp_port from sys.dm_exec_connections where local_net_address is not null
```